# Build Map like implementation in iOS Using Scroll View and Image View

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, collision-detection

I want to build a map with my own image. Image will be house plans like such. I have an implementation in my mind, just needed the experts advice here to implement it better.

My Way,

1. Setup a scroll view and image view with scrolling enabled and content offset set to image frame.
2. Set the delegate so I can zoom in / zoom out and pan over the image.
3. Once image loaded, create a custom view object to represent Pin / Marker with details like the position, image, and name and add them as subview to a image view.

That's all to present the map. But I have two important problems to deal with.

1. I should be able to detect the intersecting Pins / Markers at any edge / corner, so that I can decide whether I should display the name or not. For this I need a better collision detection algorithm(Suggest one ). The pins / marker should be redrawn every time the image is being scaled. I don't want to go with cluster algorithms to combine my pins.
2. When I resize the image view, I should maintain the position and the size of the subviews, So I guess I need to recalculate the position of views based on the scale ratio and do it inside the scrollViewDidZoom delegate.

Thats all. May not be the best way of doing, so looking for the best or say it's better.

Thanks.

Comment: Someone wanted to close this issue saying it's broad, but my question is specific, Is my approach is efficient / is there any one can approach the same problem more efficiently. It's a broad topic If I asked How to do it, but I didn't. Please justify your action when saying it needs to be closed with few lines of comments, so I can avoid the same issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I did pretty much what you describe for a client app. It was a lot of work.

Maps are usually pretty large, and can be displayed over a wide range of scales. You want them to look good from closest zoom out to the scale where your whole map fits on the screen. To do that you really need to build the map at various scales and divide it into tiles (similar to "mipmapping" commonly used in texture rendering like in OpenGL.)

That is how I built my custom map engine. I based my development on a sample app from Apple called "PhotoScroller".

However, that development was started under iOS 6. Apple has since added support for map overlays, overlay renderers, and tiled renderers. It's now possible to create your own custom map tiles and either store them on-device or download them from the 'net, without having to resort to your own custom map engine.

If I had it to do again, I would almost certainly use tiled overlays and MapKit rather than building a new map engine myself. Take a look at this tutorial online: 
[**Custom and Offline Maps Using Overlay Tiles**](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2014/01/21/custom-and-offline-maps-using-overlay-tiles/)

Comment: That's what I have been seeing all over the web. But some places I read it has issues while zooming, But never tried on my own.  I take your advice and will proceed with map tiles. And will sure to post the updates back and will do accept the answer if tiles meets all my requirement. For now Kudos (+1) for responding back. at least I have one response for my question :)

Comment: +Duncan, it's a support project, and there are lot of components built on top of it. I don't think its good to replace everything with MkMapView / TiledOverlay. So instead, I am going with old code, with a fix to place markers on image view using quad tree / k Mean cluster / collision algorithms to determine the pins to be shown at different zoom level.

Comment: Bear in mind that iOS devices are fairly memory-starved, so displaying an image that's larger than the screen can cause a great deal of memory pressure and may even cause your app to terminate. You really need to split your large images into tiles at various resolutions. Take a look at the PhotoScroller sample app from Apple (if you search on "PhotoScroller" in the Xcode help system you'll find it. That app is a working example using image tiles at a variety of scales. It does NOT show how to create the tiles however. I had to write the image tile generator myself.